# Facebook best practice for dual-authentication (client and server)?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a hosted facebook app. I hold additional PHOTO-TAG info not stored at facebook. From a device, I allow the user to (1) upload a photo, and (2) store additional photo-tag info at my server (C# MVC)

My requirements:
1. photo should go directly to fb. Don't want the user to lose it should my host go down. (I already do this).
2. additional tag info should be authenticated. [if it's not, anyone can save this info about any photo]. (I already save tag-info, but unauthorized in my sandbox)

? What's the best practice to:
Ensure that when I get a tag-save-request at my server (with a saved photo id), I can verify the user for that photo.

I can already do server-auth when FB users access my site from a desktop.
I can already do client-auth when my device app connects/uploads the photo. (using 'code' then exchanging it for a token)

But, when I pass the access-token from the client to my server, and I try to check it thru FB, I get an #804 (or 803) back about an auth-issue. Clearly not the way to do it.

Should I make my device-client go thru my server with a redirect to auth and I capture/save/create some extra token?  I'm only worried that I then wouldn't be able to upload directly to FB.    Should I pass the code and exchange it for a token at the server (after already exchanging it at the client? can you do it more than once?)

(I already know about http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ but it doesn't (that I can see) address this scenario)

Best solutions? Thanks.